# Exchange Message Tracking Attatchments

Tags: exchange-2013, powershell-v3.0

I have a requirement by which i need to export a list of all emails with an attachment that have the following words within its subject (private,confidential)

As it stands i can export all emails that contain the words outlined within the subject but do not know how to include the attatchment element;

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.MessageSubject -match "private" -or $_.MessageSubject -match "confidential"}
```

Can someone please advise, having done research i dont know if this is even possible.

Thanks